# python - huge for loop is to slow, are there a faster way to handle it

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, bigdata

I'm running a lots of data we speak about 10-15 mil. multiply times in for loop, and i can found out of its my for loop there are slow eg.

i disover the problem when i test 100 rows, then 1000 and then 25.000 rows every time i encrse my numbers of rows its taken much longer time to run.

i'm using numpy today to calculate a lots of prices and its working perfect, so now i hit the wall with so much data there shut running multi time to restructuer the data befure i'm ready to return it to a final array/dict.

a orther issue its when i run a for in a for loop, its taken much more time then a for ofc i need to run "for 1 rows * for 2 rows"

**my case is.**

1. 1.200.000 products

   1. price rules there can be hit (25-30 diff price rules)
   2. select the right price rule and do stuff based on htis rule
   3. restruter the data using for loop before using numpy
   4. calculate a price to the main product price by using numpy
2. run the product pricerule group agenst 10-15 price groups for each product

   1. restructer the data and prepare in a for loop before using numpy
   2. append the price to main product price array in for loop
3. restruter all data and prepare to return it in my array/dict so i can use it later (single / multi product calc)

hope you understand what i want, and why this will take so much time, and hope there are one there can help me to find a faster way to calculate so much data in.

i have thinking on multitread option, but i think i need to fix the main-for-loop issue before i go to the next performance setup

**a very basic sample of my case how to hit this loop in a loop hell**

```
import datetime
start_time = datetime.datetime.now()

product = []
group = []
final_collect = []

for test_product in range(25000):
    product.append({'title': test_product})

for (inx, item) in enumerate(product):
    group.append({
        'product' : item,
        'group-data' : []
    })

    for test_group in range(10):
        group[inx]['group-data'].append({'group' : test_group, 'price' : 100.0})
        print(inx, test_group)
```

as you can see this one will take around 2-3 sec to run 250.000 loops, when we speak 25.000 products, if we go to run it on 1.200.000 mil. * 10 groups its 12.000.000 loops each and i do it multiply time so its will take long time. but there shut be a faster way around this issue?

Comment: if all your data is in `data_row` why are you taking the data and appending it to a new array?

Comment: i have arrays with products, pricerules, pricerule-group, manufacuter and then i have a lots of rules i need to prepare before i calculate everything and when i'm done here i need to restruter da data becures i split it up to handle it faster in numpy, thats part working perfect, now i fight with my for loop its to slow

Comment: In all likelihood, there is probably a way to restructure your logic without explicit `for` loops. However, what you have provided is not reproducible, so it will generate votes to close. Please provide a **[mcve]**.

Comment: In your `for` loops, you seem to be using the index unnecessarily in a few places.  For example, `migrete_array[0][inx]`  could be replaced by `item`.  Not sure that it would make much difference to the performance though.  Also, why are you storing fixed strings every time: ` 'method' : 'business',
        'group-key' : 'cost-price'`, seems rather wasteful on memory.

Comment: @jp_data_analysis okay, hmm that i do not understand becures its very usefull if you handle lots of data? are i'm using the wrong place in stackoverflow? i'm have a issue with huges amount of data and if you hit 25.000+ rows in python you hit it as your self.

Comment: @cdarke sorting array everytime? can you explen?

Comment: @ParisNakitaKejser, give an example, e.g. 10 rows. The guys here are adept at multiplying data by X.

Comment: @jp_data_analysis now i have fill-out a sample, i can't do it more simple then that, its ilustarte the issue when i got to many loops and loop in a loop.

Comment: Do you use Numpy at all?

Comment: @ParisNakitaKejser: I said "storing", not "sorting".

Comment: @Joe yes, but i only use it to calcualte numbers, and thats why i have a lots of arrays i need to comparer and migrate when i'm done with everything i do.

Comment: Any reason you are not using Numpy for everything? Because this should really speed up your code.

Comment: I would avoid using lists or tuples. If you can use arrays, use arrays and not lists. Using numba, you can loop as much as you wan't and get  a better performance than with vectorized numpy code.

Comment: I think the problem is not with the loop but with the approach itself. Your `product` is a list of dicts with the same key, this is weird. Have you heard about [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/)? For example, your `group` object could be calculated with it as: `group = pd.DataFrame(dict(title=[i for i in range(25000) for _ in range(10)], group=list(range(10)) * 25000)); 
group['price'] = 100.0`. It will take less than a second. Try it out.

Comment: @Georgy Thanks a lot, what i need 100% and i have work for this in week no and now i can perfome all my data in like 5-10min :) thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`run2` below generates a 30% improvement versus equivalent `run1` (which you provided). Output is identical.

While this may not be "plug and play" for your use case, it demonstrates some of the tricks you can use to improve performance.

```
import datetime

def run1(n):
    start_time = datetime.datetime.now()

    product = []
    group = []
    final_collect = []

    for test_product in range(n):
        product.append({'title': test_product})

    for (inx, item) in enumerate(product):
        group.append({'product': item,
                      'group-data': []})

        for test_group in range(10):
            group[inx]['group-data'].append({'group': test_group, 'price': 100.0})

    return group

def run2(n):
    start_time = datetime.datetime.now()

    group = [{'product': {'title': i},
              'group-data': [{'group': test_group, 'price': 100.0} for test_group in range(10)]} \
              for i in range(n)]

    return group

assert run1(10) == run2(10)

%timeit run1(50000)  # 1 loop, best of 3: 372 ms per loop
%timeit run2(50000)  # 1 loop, best of 3: 260 ms per loop
```

Comment: looks very interesting, 30% perfomes its cool if i can get this, did you have orther ways to increase performance in huges loops?

Comment: as far as your specific example code goes, I cannot see any further optimization.